# Error message on my code

Tags: mysql

I have a script that gives an error and since I am new to this I would appreciate help.
Here is the code that gives me the following error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Thank you all for your help

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE fn=$t");
die(mysql_error());
    $arr=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
   extract($arr);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo"$fsitename"?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
</head>

<frameset rows="100,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0"> 
<frame name=visit src=<?php echo"toptask.php?t=$t&id=$id";?> frameborder=0>
<frame name=visit src=<?php echo"$furl";?> frameborder=0>

</frameset>
<noframes><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">

</body></noframes>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `$t` is empty so you get the error.

if `fn` is a char field you should use single quotes around `$t`.

**Stop using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statement.**

Comment: Thank you I try and here are the error messages:


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'sql' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in /htdocs/visit_task.php on line 4

Comment: @Sophie can you show the line 4 in `visit_task.php `

Comment: $ sql = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM taches WHERE fn = '$t' " );
die(mysql_error());

Comment: @Sophie you have a blank between `$` and `sql`at the begining of the line. please remove it.

Comment: I remove the space and now have a blank page

Comment: @Sophie Maybe because your page do not show any value?

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to help without all code, but at this line

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE fn=$t");
```

It is looking in your database and it selects every record where the column named `fn` equals to the variable `$t`. In your code I do not see this variable, so that may cause the problem.

Because I don't know the condition you want to filter for in your table, but a possible solution would be for example

```
$t = 4;
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE fn=$t");
```

or with a string:

```
$t = "John";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE fn='$t'");
```

Comment: Merci je tente et VOICI les messages d'erreur:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'sql' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in /htdocs/visit_task.php on line 4

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issues is not quoting the variable. Always quote variables which are not intenger/boolean.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE fn='$t'");
```

Hope it helps...